# How to detect if a URL has a file or not?

Tags: java, android, url, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm using Glide to load images in image view from URLs.

If the image is not available in the server and URL doesn't exit/pointing a deleted file then **the image view becomes blank..**

How to know if URL has a image or not?

```
//do magic here if/else 
     Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(myImageView);
```

Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: check the url if null or not

Comment: @Ticherhaz how to check...buddy my URLs are stored in a database...and I'm copying image url from the internet to my DB...if the image is deleted by its owner the url is still in my DB and my app will load it in imagview...and I get blank imagview

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way.

```
 Glide.with(passContext)
    .applyDefaultRequestOptions(
       new RequestOptions()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user_default)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_user_default)
     )
    .load(url)
    .into(imageview);
```

Comment: please explain what does .applyDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions() do?

Answer (score 0):

[Use `placeholder()` or `error()`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html) if your objective is to show some local image if the URL does not point to a valid image.

[Use `RequestListener`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/debugging.html#requestlistener-and-custom-logs) if you want to learn about failures more generally.